# git clone erron on react native how to resolve this

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm

I was trying to setup react native project but i got this error how to resolve this

```
npm WARN react-redux@5.0.5 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none was installed.
Installing dependencies using npm...

npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  expo/node-websql#18.0.0 resetting remote C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-17a6eb60 because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-17a6eb60: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-17a6eb60: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  expo/node-websql#18.0.0 resetting remote C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-9423671b because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-9423671b: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-9423671b: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  expo/node-websql#18.0.0 resetting remote C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-8213877d because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-8213877d: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-git-18-0-0-8213877d: undefined
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\VA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-17T09_17_53_803Z-debug.log
`npm install --save` failed
```

Comment: This is not a git clone error, this is a npm install error. You are probably missing the git executable (or it is not correctly defined in your PATH)

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have installed **GIT** in your machine, If not, go and grab a copy here => https://git-scm.com/downloads and download/install based on your environment.

If you already have any other git client (like, SmartGit, TortoiseGIT or SourceTree) you can use the below command to set the path to point the portable git.

`set path=%PATH%;YOUR_GIT_PATH`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - in my case it had to do with Cygwin. The install script requires absolute paths starting with `c:\` but in a Cygwin environment this would be something like `/cygdrive/c/`. The required paths can't be resolved and the installation fails.

In that case the solution is simple: Exit Cygwin and use the standard shell for `npm i`.